# Разные explain для одного запроса

Tags: explain, mysql

У меня есть две базы данных у одного хостера - dev и prod. dev - это вчерашняя копия prod.
При выборке из них данных одним и тем же запросом - разные результаты по времени: dev - 44 sec, prod - 1 sec(смотрел show profiles). Я всегда думал что explain зависит от структуры таблиц и самого запроса, а тут выяснилось, что он разный. 
Что еще может влиять на план выполнения запроса?

И чем определяется порядок строк в плане? Он отражает реальную последовательность действий?

**explain dev:** [image: explain dev]

**explain prod:** [image: explain prod]

Comment: покажите выводы explain, без этого наверняка сказать нельзя.

Comment: добавил скрины

Comment: Проверьте, что индексы на таблицах идентичны. Вообще, на план запроса влияет статистика, накапливаемая сервером отдельно для каждой базы. Случается, что в один прекрасный день запрос на одной и той же базе начинается исполняться по-другому.

Comment: Структура таблиц идентична, а вот про статистику похоже на правду, так как периодически запросы к продакшену так же начинают тормозить. Я не могу придумать как сделать, чтобы они стабильно быстро выполнялись. Только арендовать свой сервер и крутить my.cnf?

Comment: Я не сильно осведомлен в тюнинге MySQL, увы. Надо подождать еще кого-нибудь.

Answer (score 2):

Перед выполнением любого запроса, mysql просматривает все возможные (ну или [почти все](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/controlling-query-plan-evaluation.html)) планы выполнения запроса, оценивает их стоимость и выбирает план с наилучшей (читай - наименьшей) стоимостью.

О примерном механизме построения плана написано в [документации](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/optimizer-joins-access-methods.html).

Оценка проходит рекурсивно в несколько этапов. На каждом этапе выбирается определенная таблица и получается оценка добавления этой таблицы в текущий план выполнения.

Если коротко, то на оценку плана влияют следующие параметры (для текущей таблицы):

- число строк в таблице
- ограничения в условии WHERE
- длинные ключи таблицы
- уникальный или первичный ключ
- полнотекстовый индекс
- число стоблцов в ключе
- размер файла таблицы
- покрывающие индексы
- и т.д.

Т.е. если в запросе используется первичный ключ для текущей просматриваемой таблицы, то это положительно скажется на оценке общего плана выполнения. Если в запросе используется полнотекстовый индекс, то это отрицательно скажется на оценке и т.д.

Если вы выполняли множество операций добавления/удаления строк, то файл таблицы может разрастись. Но при импорте этой таблицы на другой сервер данные будут располагаться уже рядом, что уменьшит размер файла, а это тоже влияет на оценку.

Кроме того, если в запросе используется индекс, то на оценку плана может сильно повлиять кардинальность этого индекса.

Кардинальность же для InnoDB [рассчитывается следующим образом](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-statistics-estimation.html): при первом открытии таблицы, при выполнении `ANALYZE TABLE` или `SHOW TABLE STATUS` происходят случайные считывания нескольких страниц индекса. На основе этих считываний и определяется кардинальность.

Таким образом, даже на одном и том же сервере, если размеры таблиц достаточно велики, то кардинальность индекса может меняться. И связано это будет со случайной природой определения кардинальности, а не с тем, что настоящая кардинальность индекса действительно изменилась.

Но кардинальность может измениться и другим способом: изменив число страниц, которые mysql случайно просматривает для получения кардинальности, (`innodb_stats_sample_pages`) мы можем увеличить или уменьшить точность полученного значения.

Раз изменилась кардинальность индекса, то изменится и оценка для данного плана и этот план может оказаться уже не таким оптимальным.

Таким образом, на порядок подключения таблиц в запросе влияет множество различных факторов. Но раз базы практически идентичны, то основное отличие в планах выполнения будет обусловлено либо статистикой, либо разными физическими размерами (например, размер файла таблицы, или, возможно, размер оперативной памяти), либо параметрами конфигурации mysql

Если вы уверены, что для вашего запроса будет оптимальным определенный порядок подключения таблиц, то можно сказать это mysql, использовав `STRAIGHT_JOIN` (см. [документацию](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html))

---

P.S.: под словосочетанием "*в запросе используется индекс*" имеется ввиду следующее: если при добавлении очередной таблицы оптимизатор видит что можно включить использование индекса таблицы, то он (оптимизатор) оценивает план как с этим индексом, так и без него. Поэтому, при наличии нескольких индексов, можно наблюдать как используются то одни, то другие индексы.

Кстати, наличие индекса не всегда означает его использование. Например, если есть индекс по столбцу `color`, кардинальность которого очень мала (например, всего 8 цветов в базе на миллион записей) и выборка будет вида `select * from table_name where color = 0`, то mysql может решить, что при использовании индекса придется совершить очень много случайных чтений с диска, что будет стоить намного дороже последовательного чтения данных без  просмотра индекса. А значит индекс будет проигнорирован.